# How can I use animation-list in a fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am newbie in using Android Studio.

I have tried to use animation list to do the animation on fragment, but after I have ran my code, my png were not shown on the screen.

here is my code in my animation xml file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/baby1" android:duration="100" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/baby2" android:duration="1000" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/baby1" android:duration="100" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/baby2" android:duration="300" />

</animation-list>
```

Then, here is in my fragment file

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    View myGotRex = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    imageView = (ImageView)myGotRex.findViewById(R.id.imageBaby);
    if(imageView == null) throw new AssertionError();
    imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.animation_baby);

    anim = (AnimationDrawable)imageView.getBackground();
    anim.start();

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
}
```

I wondered that does the animation list works with fragment or not?

Comment: Return myGotRex from the onCreateView() method.

Comment: Just one line! Thanks! You save my life!